# embeding vlc plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am trying to embed the vlc player from the following link

http://wiki.videolan.org/HowTo_Integrate_VLC_plugin_in_your_webpage

I am getting  a message a missing plugin in mozilla,what plugin should be installed to get this working

```
 <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script language="javascript" src="http://revolunet.github.com/VLCcontrols/src/jquery-vlc.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://revolunet.github.com/VLCcontrols/src/styles.css" /> 
 <script language="javascript">
   var player = VLCobject.embedPlayer('vlc1', 400, 300);
   player.play('http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi');
</script>
```

`EDIT`

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="player" autoplay="no" loop="no" target="udp:@239.255.12.42" />
  <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script language="javascript" src="http://revolunet.github.com/VLCcontrols/src/jquery-vlc.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://revolunet.github.com/VLCcontrols/src/styles.css" />
     <script language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var player = VLCobject.embedPlayer('vlc1', 400, 300);
         player.play('http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi');
     });
  </script>
  </head>
     <body>
     <div id="vlc1" name="vlc1" class="vlc1" ></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is fine with your code, I would try to load this on document ready or move the above code block before the closing  tag.

And you could take some time and share what is the missing plugin in mozilla and show more code like the block element you are trying to load vlc into.

EDIT:

For windows, see this: 
http://wiki.videolan.org/Windows#VLC_Plugin_for_Firefox_.28Mozilla.29

If not, tell your OS.

Comment: But as per their code it should work on any just plain html right?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that. If you have the above code in your <head> and the div where you load the content is somewhere in the body, by the time var player = VLCobject.embedPlayer('vlc1', 400, 300); is called you don't have the vlc1 element loaded and might fire an error.

Comment: Ah and if you are saying that there is block element with sad face "missing plugin" then you have to install the VLC-Plugin for mozilla! It can't work otherwise, I though that there is some kind of JS/mozilla plugin error but this is expected behaviour. What OS do you need the plugin for?

Comment: Please see the edit of my question that is how i am trying to invoke it..Also can u please let me know where the plugin is i can t find one..

Comment: Will have a look at this .Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to install VLC player on your system. While installing check **delete the cache and preferences** option and refresh your page once installed.